# Updating state with array

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to update the `state` with an array. As you can see if I `console.log` array then it works well but if I try to update with `setLetter()` then it just keeps pushing the same element. I want to use this like typing effect.. How can I solve this? Thanks!

```
const [letter, setLetter] = useState("");

const text = `hello, world.`
let i = 0;
let array = [];

useEffect(() => {
let interval = setInterval(() => {
                if(letter.length < text.length){
                    array.push(...text[i]);
                    i++;
                    console.log(array);
                    // setLetter(letter => [...letter, ...array]);
                } else {
                    return () => clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }, 300);
            return () => clearInterval(interval);
})
```

Comment: your initialstate is an string and you cannot update the state With array.

Comment: yeah it was my mistake, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this may helpful for you

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Sof() {
    const [letter, setLetter] = useState([]);

const text = `hello, world`
let i = 0;
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(()=>{
        setLetter((letter)=>[...letter, text[i]])
        i++
    if(i === text.length){
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 200);
    return () => {
            clearInterval(interval)
    }
}, [])
return (
    <div>
       {letter}
    </div>
)
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, I don't have to use useRef if I use this code :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the way that you are iterate is wrong. I changed your code and it works now.

first solution

```
   const [letter, setLetter] = useState("");
      const text = `hello, world.`;
      let array = [];
      useEffect(() => {
        let interval = setInterval(() => {
          if (letter.length < text.length) {
            for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
              array.push(text[i]);
            }
    
            setLetter((letter) => [...letter, ...array]);
          } else {
            return () => clearInterval(interval);
          }
        }, 300);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
      });
```

second solution

```
const [letter, setLetter] = useState("");
  const text = `hello, world.`;
  let array = [];
  useEffect(() => {
    if (letter.length < text.length) {
      for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        array.push(text[i]);
      }

      setLetter((letter) => [...letter, ...array]);
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: I runed code on my ide and get error for text[i] equal to undefined and chenge the code and it works

Comment: I was trying to ask push each letter inside of array and update on letter state, so It looks like a typing effect..  maybe I asked in a wrong way

Comment: if I click the button "h" will be rendered, and after 300 ms "he" and then ... "hel".

Comment: @young Do you want to see text after the click button?

Answer (score -3):

I solved it using `useRef()`.

```
const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
const [letter, setLetter] = useState("");

let countRef = useRef(0);

const text = `hello, world.`

let array = [];

const handleClick = () => {
   setClicked(!clicked);
}

useEffect(() => {
     if(clicked){
        let interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (countRef.current < text.length) {
                array.push(...text[countRef.current]);
                countRef.current = countRef.current + 1;
                setLetter(letter => [...letter, ...array]);
            } else {    
                return () => clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 300);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
     }
})
```